# Is there any way to assign multiple strings on the same line using cin?

Tags: c++

I've just started learning C++ and I've done some googling but can't seem to find a solid answer.

is there anyway to input multiple strings variables on the same line using cin.

for example say you wanted someone to enter there first and last name on the same line and then assign them to the varibales firstname and lastname.

asides from having multiple lines and prompting them twice how would you do this?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){

    string firstname;
    string lastname;

    cout << "Please enter your first name: \n" ;

    cin >> firstname;

    cout << "Please enter your last name: \n";


    cin >> lastname;

    cout << "Your full name is  : " << firstname <<" "<< lastname;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `std::cin >> firstname >> lastname;`?

Comment: You should not be using `std::cin` to accept strings from the standard input. Use  `std::getline` instead.

Comment: @Ron Why not? Seems like dogma to me.

Comment: @Ron and why? I mean especially if the OP wants that the user can enter first and last name in one line.

Comment: As a note: reading it in one line can be ambiguous because first- or last names theoretically can consist out of multiple words.

Comment: @Ron that's what the OP wants `Firstname Lastname`. And how would `std::getline` solve that problem there?

Comment: @Ron does have a point: e.g. Ludwig van Beethoven.

Comment: @Bathsheba that's true but that's no `std::cin` vs `std::getline` but a general problem of the wish of the OP to read it in one line. And `std::getline` does not help there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible:

```
std::string firstname, lastname;
std::cout << "Please enter your full name:\n";
std::cin >> firstname >> lastname;
std::cout << "Your full name is  : " << firstname << ' ' << lastname;
```

Since `operator>>` for `std::cin` returns a reference to `std::cin`, it can be chained together, just like `std::cout`.

Comment: Thank you!  although now Im a bit confused. Some of the comments mentioned using getline. is there any advantage to doing so?

Comment: @BlueTeam if the first or last name may be multiple words, it is more reasonable to use `std::getline`. That is because in the case of names like "Ludwig van Beethoven", `std::cin` would read "Ludwig" as the first name and "van" as last name. If you are sure such a thing is not going to happen, `std::cin` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation it really helped!

Comment: @BlueTeam please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you only want to use the cin function, you should try; `cin >> firstname >> lastname` and prompt to the user to enter his/her name in this format: "john smith", "jane smith", as the space causes the cin function to accept it as a different input altogether thus making the program enter the first name and then last name.

Sorry for any grammatical answers.
EDIT: I should mention I mean the format within the quotes, as in entering the first name, space, last name.

Comment: `std::cin` is not a function. It's an object. `std::cin >> firstname;` calls the function `operator<<(istream&, std::string&)`.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies. I never knew that! Thanks.